# Is it possible to keep mysql migration running without keeping connection open?

Tags: mysql

`ALTER TABLE` can easily take a few days - and during this time there's a non-negligible chance of connection getting terminated due to network problems. Is it possible to start `ALTER TABLE` (or `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT ...`; or some other very long running query) and leave it running without keeping connection open all the time?

(the obvious solution of screen + console mysql client won't easily work as there's no ssh running on that server, only mysqld).

Answer (score 0):

Put your alter table command in a script that you will call from a shell script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

muser=username
mpass=password
mhost=hostname
mdb=databasename

mysql --user=$muser --password=$mpass --host=$mhost $mdb < alter.sql
```

then call the shell script with nohup

```
nohup myscript.ksh >logfile 2>&1 &
```

You can log out of the shell session immediately afterwards.  You may get a warning message that you have running jobs, but it is safe to ignore.

You can probably skip the sql script and put the commands in the shell script.  I just don't recall the syntax

Comment: If it wasn't immediately clear from my answer, you can run this from any linux/unix box that can remotely connect to the mysql database

Comment: This will not work at all, because as I said, there's only mysql on the server, not any sort of ssh. If I start a script such on another machine, network connection can fail during all the days it runs.

Comment: first, you're connecting to the database via the mysql command in the shell script, not via ssh.  second, read the man page for nohup.  this is exactly what it is designed for - long-running jobs where there is a risk that the connection will be terminated.  note also that I'm logging the output and putting the job in the background